# React redirection page with history.push give a bad url

Tags: reactjs

I have a button and when press this button execute the function `createEvent` and this put in the page with url

> mypage.com/event/create

If I press this again because is a component that I used in all page even in th create my url is:

> mypage.com/event/event/create

and get error `page not found`
my function:

```
     const history = useHistory();
     const createEvent = () => {
        history.push('event/create');
      };
```

Comment: Add a leading slash to your target path: `history.push('/event/create');`.

Comment: @George that it, thanks